# Connecting storage account datalake 2 to log analytics workspace

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a storage account **datalake** Gen2.
I need to connect my storage account logs to a Log analytics workspace.

But there is no **Diagnostic Settings** menu, so I don't know how to do.

I think this was supported by datalake Gen1, but is there a workaround for datalake gen 2?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Diagnostic settings option at the end of the left sidebar, but you have to scroll quite a bit to find it.

Sadly, i believe currently there is no such option to automatically send diagnostic logs to a log analytics workspace. The active logs will be generated inside a folder named "$logs" located on the root path of your storage account, its only visible through Azure storage explorer.

Microsoft provides a Powershell script located at [Azure GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-samples/blob/master/storage/post-storage-logs-to-log-analytics/PostStorageLogs2LogAnalytics.ps1) which aims to upload the log files generated to a log analytics workspace of your choice.

You can refer to this official guide from Microsoft to build this workflow to send your logs to log analytics: [Querying Azure Storage logs in Azure Monitor Log Analytics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9fx5bFMYjQ)

Comment: After doing some more test, this solution does not work for datalake, only blob storage account